# salesforce push notification to salesforce for android

Tags: push-notification, salesforce, apex

I need to send a push notification to salesforce built in mobile app salesforce for  android, I have the app as a connected app to my org.

I have apex code which sends notification when case is created

```
 msg.send('Salesforce for Android',users);
```

I get error as 
       "NoAccessExpection: common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Invalid 
       connected application: Salesforce for Android"

Answer (score 0):

You should pass API name as a parameter, not label. API name doesn't have space. Please check the link below:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_push_notification.htm